# Deploying Node.js app to Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, deployment

I haven't found much documentation on transferring *existing* apps to Firebase. I have a sample, one page Node.js app that just emails data submitted to a form: https://github.com/agreyfield91/Nodemailer-Firebase-App.

I would like to deploy this app to firebase. From what I've made out, I have to first `firebase init functions`, in order to have my "firebase-functions" index.js created inside of a functions folder. What do I do then? Can I simply copy paste my original index.js code into the firebase-created index.js?

Comment: Should help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8

Comment: That video is about creating a firebase app from scratch - I would like to know how to simply transfer my existing app, since I have structures that I would not like to change.

Comment: Sure but it clearly shows how to adapt your app to firebase environment

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to deploy a plain node.js app without modification to Cloud Functions.  Cloud Functions is not a "server" environment.  It's "serverless", which means you write code that responds to events that happen in your project, or HTTPS requests, and the server instances that execute it will automatically scale up or down to match the load that's being placed on it.

If you have an existing Express app that you want to run on Cloud Functions, you will, at the very least, have to write some code to hook up your Express app so that Cloud Functions knows how to trigger it.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for hosting services that can directly deploy node apps?

Comment: Take a look at Heroku or Now.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, we can with Firebase Hosting now.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=17&v=LOeioOKUKI8

Comment: You could include something more from the links here.